# How get cosine similarity from pandas data

Tags: python, pandas

i have list pandas like :

```
data = [
    ('1', '2', 8, 10),
    ('2', '1', 2, 7),
    ('4', '3', 3, 9),
    ('3', '4', 5, 6)
  ]
  print data
  df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id_sender', 'id_receiver', 'freq', 'sum'])
  print df

id_sender | id_receiver | freq | sum
1         | 2           | 10   | 5
2         | 1           | 7    | 4
3         | 4           | 4    | 8
4         | 3           | 3    | 5
```

i need to get cosine similarity between `id_sender` and `id_receiver` based on `freq` and `sum`, where `id_sender` and `id_receiver` with two way direction

```
similarity(1,2) = similarity([10 5], [7,4])
```

i have tried using pivot, but it's not working, i mean i don't how to pivot with this type table.

Comment: yes,,, i have use cosine similarity from scipy...but for another data...such as product bought per user,,,,

Comment: try [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). It lets you apply (!) a function on each row of your dataset.